# Is it normal that model output slightly different on different platforms?

Tags: python, gpu, huggingface-transformers, embedding, bert-language-model

I am using Huggingface to generate bert embedding for text, but they are slightly different for the same text on my Mac and Linux platforms. For examples, one pair of results:

Mac

```
[0.9832047820091248, 0.8559693694114685, 0.9794790744781494, 0.8379054069519043, 0.2829965651035309, 0.16260339319705963, -0.6263850927352905, -0.6327080130577087, 0.255816787481308, -0.993371307849884, 0.9957219958305359, 0.9640689492225647, 
...
0.8542048931121826, -0.3760552406311035, 0.8242940902709961, 0.7799679636955261, -0.9965563416481018, -0.44975095987319946, -0.7121481895446777, 0.9866052269935608]
```

Ubuntu:

```
[0.98320472240448, 0.8559693694114685, 0.9794790148735046, 0.8379054069519043, 0.2829962372779846, 0.16260334849357605, -0.6263852715492249, -0.6327071189880371, 0.25581657886505127, -0.993371307849884, 0.9957219958305359, 0.9640689492225647, 
...
-0.8621405363082886, -0.9272670745849609, 0.8125085234642029, 0.6777691841125488, 0.8542047739028931, -0.3760542571544647, 0.8242939114570618, 0.7799678444862366, -0.9965563416481018, -0.4497515857219696, -0.7121477127075195, 0.986605167388916]
```

As you can see, those numbers are almost the same, but the last few digits for each float is different. On Linux it uses multiple GPUS, and on Mac it uses CPUs.

The code looks like the following:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("hfl/chinese-roberta-wwm-ext", model_max_length=128)
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained("hfl/chinese-roberta-wwm-ext")
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
        model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
        #model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1])
    model = model.to(device)
inputs = tokenizer(names, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
outputs = model(**inputs)
embeddings = outputs[1].cpu().detach().numpy().tolist()
```

For those small differences, it shouldn't affect similarity computation? The reason I am asking this is that I got different similarity performance on Mac and Linux based on Bert embedding, but the datasets are not exactly the same. One is a subset of another. So the difference might be due to either the dataset itself, or the different embedding vector.

So those small embedding vector differences are normal when generating on different platforms, including CPU and GPU?

Comment: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn So it is normal?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer helpful and thought I would share:

> Why Does It Happen?
>
> When running TensorFlow code on different devices, we may get different results due to a variety of reasons. One of the main reasons is the difference in the hardware architecture of the devices. CPU and GPU have different architectures, and they process data differently. For example, CPU is optimized for serial processing, while GPU is optimized for parallel processing. This means that the same code may execute differently on CPU and GPU, leading to different results.
>
> Another reason for different results could be the difference in the precision of the computations. GPU devices can perform computations with higher precision than CPU devices, which can lead to different results. This is because GPUs use a different floating-point format than CPUs. GPUs use the IEEE 754-2008 half-precision format (FP16), while CPUs use the IEEE 754-2008 single-precision format (FP32). This difference in precision can cause small variations in the results.

https://saturncloud.io/blog/tensorflow-same-code-but-different-results-on-cpu-and-gpu/