# Why do sentence transformers produce slightly different embeddings for the same text?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I noticed that a sentence, say, "This is a first sentence", produces a slightly different embedding depending on the context of other sentences that are encoded along with it:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer("distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v1")
embeddings1 = model.encode(["This is a first sentence"])
embeddings2 = model.encode(["This is a first sentence", "This is another sentence"])
embeddings1[0,:5]
embeddings2[0,:5]
embeddings2[1,:5]
```

This produces the following output:

```
array([0.026788  , 0.02391568, 0.00314784, 0.10020158, 0.02555996], dtype=float32)
array([0.02678801, 0.02391565, 0.00314785, 0.10020156, 0.02555998], dtype=float32)
array([ 0.01069314, -0.02397677,  0.0074933 ,  0.03367725,  0.04727736], dtype=float32)
```

Notice how the first two vectors in that output are not quite the same. This happens for a couple of other sentence transformer models I've tested as well.

Is this due to rounding error and if so, how does that happen? Or is it expected behavior explained in some way, e.g., by the attention mechanism?

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084 Here is the paper published on the documentation of Sentence Transformer. I believe it can answer your question.

Comment: I didn't find an answer in that paper, @Sam, would you kindly point me to it?

Comment: In the pdf given in the link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.10084.pdf, "*a modification of the pretrained BERT network that use siamese and triplet network structures to derive semantically meaningful sentence embeddings that can be compared using cosine-similarity*" mentioned in Page 1, then directly to Page 3, where you can find your mentioned issue (but in a lot of detail). TLDR; It uses cosine-similarity between the two sentences to indicate similarity between them, and outputs embeddings accordingly.

Comment: @Sam, I think I'm asking something different. I noticed that the SAME input produces sliiiightly different output on different 'runs' ..so I'm not talking about cosine similarity between sentences. My issue may be more related to this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729241/is-it-normal-that-model-output-slightly-different-on-different-platforms

Comment: @Terry.d It is not a sentence-transformer bug. At the moment it seems like a matrix multiplication issue, but it is still under investigation. You can follow this [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2401).

Comment: Thanks, @cronoik, this is helpful!